# Is UI thread blocked even when we have many fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to understand the following:
If we do a design of an activity that the UI is composed by multiple "child" fragments of that activity, if 1 of those fragments does something "costly" in the UI thread in the `onCreateView` does this affect all of the fragments?
Because if I understand correctly `onCreateView` is called only once

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will affect all the Fragments if the Actvity they are attached to is affected. 
According to Android Developer Guide on Fragment, once the Fragment is attached to the Activity, it's Life Cycle is controlled by the Activity e.g. if Activity is Destroyed the Fragment is too. 
Fragment is just a like a little Activity so if there is possibility that fragment operation is likely to be long then AsyncTask or any other suitable service should be used. See below link for more details on Background Services;

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: If the operation is `onCreateView` which is called once, does this mean that this will cause an issue only once in the lifecycle?

Comment: You shouldn't call it in onCreateView call Operations Like that in onActivityAttach() and yes if its long operation and  not run off ui thread it will throw an exception

Comment: So what will happen exactly? If there is some kind of time out an exception will be thrown and the fragment will not load or the activity will also crash?

Comment: Activity might load but not showing any data if it is time out e.g. if fragment was unable to get data from.server or return null response, there is possibility the activity is shown or not in a case of sending List to Adapter class will cause null value sent to list.size(). However to avoid error like that, I will have a default value to show if e.g. webservice returns null. The bottom line is ERROR is error and therefore not good for User's Experience is not caught

Comment: `Activity might load but not showing any data` you mean for that fragment not show any data or for all fragments?

Comment: I don't know what you configuration is but if you using static fragments then if any of them crash the activity then they all crash

Comment: I don't know what is a `static fragment`. I only know about `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction` and use that to add fragments

Comment: Static fragment is fragment add to the Activity Layout in XML and can not be added or removed. Dynamic fragments however give flexibility in adding and replacing fragments using frgamentManager and FrgamentTransaction.

Comment: So for dynamic fragment what happens in this case?

Comment: The activity will add the fragment if is the case of time out and null value is returned but it will still throw exception if you calling an Adapter that requires List  within your fragment if you don't provide default data should the List is null.

Answer (score -1):

yes
it is effect all of the app